# Stop exoplayer playing video in background

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer

I am using exoplayer for playing video in recyclerview. I retrieve videos from firebase and play it in exoplayer .But the problem I am facing is all the videos play simultaneously in background and get the messed up. Also it consumes lots of data. If onces the video complete playing the it don't get start again. How can I stop them playing in the background. Here is my code

```
val uri = Uri.parse(contentDTOs[p1].videourl)
    val view = viewholder.findViewById<SimpleExoPlayerView>(R.id.detailviewitem_video_contents)
    val exoplayer= ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context,trackSelector)
    val datasourcefactory = DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer")
    val extractorsFactory=DefaultExtractorsFactory()
    val media = ExtractorMediaSource(uri,datasourcefactory,extractorsFactory,null,null)
    view.player = exoplayer
    exoplayer.prepare(media)
    exoplayer.playWhenReady = true
    val loopingSource = LoopingMediaSource(media)
    exoplayer.playWhenReady = true
    exoplayer.prepare(loopingSource)

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    exoplayer.stop()
}
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    exoplayer.stop()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving lines that set `playWhenReady = true` to `onResume()`. Using `.play()` instead of `playWhenReady = true` in `onResume()` could be safer (less buggy for your use-case), though.

Comment: How will I use .play()

Comment: take a look at this sample, the .play() is used there: https://exoplayer.dev/hello-world.html

Comment: glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

You should release your player. For release exoPlayer:

```
private void releasePlayer() {
    if (player != null) {
        player.release();
        player = null;
    }
}
```

And call `releasePlayer` method form life-cycle method like below:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (Util.SDK_INT < 24) {
        releasePlayer();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (Util.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        releasePlayer();
    }
}
```

Comment: No bro its not working still I am facing the problem